# Not able to loop through the column

Tags: python, pandas, function

```
def sentiment_score(comment):
    tokens = tokenizer.encode(comment, return_tensors='pt')
    result = model(tokens)
    return int(torch.argmax(result.logits))+1
    enter code here

df["sentiment"] = df['Ticket satisfaction comment'].apply(lambda x:sentiment_score(x[:500]))
```

**I'm trying to loop through every single comment in Ticket Satisfaction comment column but I'm getting the error float' object is not subscriptable. Not sure how to resolve this. Someone please help me resolve the error.**

[image]

Comment: Where exactly are you getting that error? Perhaps you could add the exact stack trace to your question by editing it.

Comment: @JonSG I have added the error screenshot please have a look at it!

Comment: It would seem that `x` is a float, which means that at least one row of `df['Ticket satisfaction comment']` does not contain the data type that you think it does.